# Is it possible to transfer/share a disk from a spot vm to a regular vm in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have a spot vm on Azure that I set up for testing a game server but the eviction/deallocation is really annoying when I'm in the middle of setup. Is it possible to transfer over the OS and Storage disks to another normal VM while I do my setup work and then switch back later? Is it possible for 2 VMs to share these disks simulataneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can transfer a disk between machines. For an OS disk you would need to delete the VM currently using it (but preserve the disk) and create a new VM from an existing disk as demonstrated [here](https://aidanfinn.com/?p=20448).

For a data disk you can detach it from the old VM and attach it to the new.

VM's can't share OS disks. It is possible to share a data disk using [Azure Shared Disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-shared) but this has strict requirements for use.